HTML＆CSS メディアクエリについて。
メディアクエリ内にレイアウト用の記述を追加すればスマートフォンで見たときだけサイドバーを隠して1カラムにすることもできるとは、どういう記述をすれば良いのでしょうか?
出典元は「そろそろ常識？マンガでわかるHTML＆CSS (赤松公太郎 著)」の第6章、最後のページです。
メディアクエリに関するコードは以下になります。教えて頂けると幸いです。
respon.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
  <meta charset=″utf-8″>
  <meta name=″viewport″ content=″width=device-width,initial-scale=1″>
  <title>Campus Art</title>
  <link rel=″stylesheet″ href=″style.css″>
</head>

style.css
@media (max-width: 599px){
  main{
    width: 90%;
  }
  main img
    width: 100%;
  }
}


@media (max-width: 599px){ ... } というのは、ブラウザの横幅が 599px以下 であれば { ... } 内の css が適用されるということです。
「スマートフォンで見たときだけ」ということではなく、スマートフォンに限らずデスクトップ PC でも同じことで、ブラウザの横幅が 599px 以下であればということです。
参考:
https://www.tohoho-web.com/css/rule/media.htm

メディアクエリ内にレイアウト用の記述を追加すればスマートフォンで見たときだけサイドバーを隠して1カラムにすることもできるとは、どういう記述をすれば良いのでしょうか?これについてはどうなるのでしょうか?

あなたの言う「スマートフォンで見たときだけ」とはどういうことですか？ 「ブラウザの横幅が 599px以下 であれば」ということでいいのですか？
